# Ubuntu stuck at cursor blinking

Tags: boot

Ubuntu stuck at cursor blinking. I have dual boot windows 7 and Ubuntu 18 . It was working fine since 7 months but yesterday Ubuntu is stuck at cursor blinking but windows 7 is running fine. I have tried advanced options for Ubuntu , recovery mode but is also stuck at blinking cursor. I have single harddrive, on which I did partition during installation.Please help I have my exams in two days and all my study material is on Ubuntu and I can't access it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

You can always boot from a LiveUSB and access your files.

Comment: Thanks for your help. If I reinstall Ubuntu using liveusb and install with option of not changing files. Does that affect my windows 7 because I don't want to lose both os simultaneously.

Comment: What do you mean by "option of not changing files"? I've never seen such an option.

Comment: I mean reinstall Ubuntu , not clean install

Comment: That shouldn't affect Windows.